# Javascript how to target double quotes within double quotes.. and display them in browser

Tags: javascript, regex

This is about retaining literal data in HTML via js writes in a browser.

Sample code...when I display this in Javascript, using `document.write`:

```html
<html>
<script>

FULL = `
{
    "key": "something",
    "value": "{\n    \"theId\": \"our_id\"}",
    "futureData": "{\"myEvent\":\"\\\"UNCHANGED\\\"\",\"myEventTimestamp\":\"\\\"2023-03-16T14:44:36.639\\\"\"}"
}
`           
; 
document.write('<pre>'+FULL+'</pre>'); 


</script>
</html>
```

In HTML, even if I wrap it around with `<pre>` it loses the slashes and messes around with the new line character, etc. How can I ensure the `document.write` does NOT lose the slashes and newline, and shows the data exactly as it's in the codes? This is what it looks like:

```
{
    "key": "something",
    "value": "{
    "cdrId": "our_id"}",
    "futureData": "{"myEvent":"\"UNCHANGED\"","myEventTimestamp":"\"2023-03-16T14:44:36.639\""}"
}
```

Some slashes are gone.. the newline character is gone.

Any ideas on how to retain the text with JS when printing in HTML? The way the code block does here on this website!

Comment: The escape sequences are replaced with their corresponding characters when the script is parsed. There's no "backslash n" in the string, it has already been turned into a newline.

Comment: If you want literal `\n` in the string, you have to escape the backslash: `\\n`.

Comment: Yes, but how `FULL.replace('\n', '\\n')` does not work.

Comment: `FULL = FULL.replaceAll('\n', '\\n')` should do it.

Comment: But this will also replace the newlines you typed explicitly in the string. There's no way to tell how a newline was entered.

Comment: One by one then. First, I need to target the slashes. Can't JS print that literal text as it is? Same as `\n`... if so, how does this website do it? Via some kind of _encoding_ of these slashes? In server side tech like PHP this is easy (`htmlencoding` for eg)..

Comment: What output do you need?  Do you literally want slashes in that output?

Comment: I want the output in HTML page to be exactly as it's written inside the `document.write()` block. As happens on this website too :)

Comment: You problem is that double solidus in JavaScript strings `(\\)` is interpreted as a single backslash.  There is nothing to replace or escape.  You string contains single backslashes.

Comment: Then how does this website, and many others, retain this and show it? Do they change the text of what I've written? The markdown stuff.

Comment: The simple solution to me seems to use the `&quot;` as it is intended here ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Comment: This website, and many others, doesn't start off with a JavaScript string literal. The string that is entered by the user is kept as it is. You are _entering_ the string wrong. In a JavaScript [string _literal_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)), `\n` means newline, always; `\\` represents a single backslash, always. The solutions are only two: load the string in some way other than a string literal (from storage, from an AJAX request, from user input, from a CDATA element...), or change the literal to correctly reflect your intention.

Comment: There is a single exception, which I don't see used very often: [raw strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#raw_strings). However, this is a rather advanced concept; you should rather aim to understand literals first, which are one of the basic concepts in many programming languages, not only JavaScript.

Comment: For an analogy, this is like asking how to get eggs out of a cake. The process of putting eggs into cake involves getting rid of the shell and blending the contents; once you do that, there is no way to restore the whole egg. The only way to get the egg from a cake is to put a whole one on the cake in the first place, shell and all. The process of putting a string literal into JavaScript code involves transforming escape sequences like `\n`; just like there is no shell in the cake, there is no `\n` in your string. It is not a problem of display, but of putting it in in th first place.

Comment: (And I run into a similar problem in comments: a backtick, two backslashes and a backtick get interpreted as `\\`, not as a code-block double-backslash as I desired. A perfect example. Yes, Stack Overflow also transforms the input, according to Markdown rules, and my Markdown input was incorrect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you write:

> First, I need to target the slashes. Can't JS print that literal text as it is?

The answer is, yes, using the [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) tag function. Note however, that substitutions, like `${foo}` are still supported. If you don't want that either, then you need to escape those.

As to escaping characters for HTML, there are really only the characters "&" and "<" that (sometimes) need to be escaped. So you could do this:

```js
const FULL = String.raw`
{
    "key": "something",
    "value": "{\n    \"theId\": \"our_id\"}",
    "futureData": "{\"myEvent\":\"\\\"UNCHANGED\\\"\",\"myEventTimestamp\":\"\\\"2023-03-16T14:44:36.639\\\"\"}"
}
`.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;");    

document.write('<pre>'+FULL+'</pre>');
```

Note that the "problem" you encountered has nothing to do with `document.write` or HTML rendering. The string given to `document.write` didn't have the "lost" backslashes, so `document.write` faithfully rendered what you gave to it. If you would have used `console.log` instead of `document.write` you would also have seen that your `FULL` string variable didn't have those backslashes.

Realise that the string literal notation in your assignment to `FULL` involves escaping itself! Backslash has a special meaning in a string literal, and so you never really have them in your string from the outset. With `String.raw` you can eliminate this special behaviour of backslashes, but this has little practical use, since you would typically get the string from elsewhere (user input, http response, ...).

Comment: Notice that even in `String.raw` there are characters that you need to escape

Comment: Yes, added a phrase about that.

Comment: Briliiant comment. `String.raw` is what I needed. Amazing, thank you.

Answer (score -3):

You can use JavaScript's `decodeURIComponent()` function to achieve this.

```
<script>
    FULL = `
    {
        "key": "something",
        "value": "{\\n    \\"theId\\": \\"our_id\\"}",
        "futureData": "{\\"myEvent\\":\\"\\\\\\"UNCHANGED\\\\\\",\\"myEventTimestamp\\":\\"\\\\\\"2023-03-16T14:44:36.639\\\\\\"\\"}"
    }
    `;
    document.write('<pre>' + decodeURIComponent(escape(FULL)) + '</pre>');
</script>
```

The `escape()` function encodes special characters, preserving the newlines and backslashes in your JSON string and `decodeURIComponent()` is used to decode the escaped characters and get the original content back.

Comment: `escape()` is non-standard and deprecated. Why didn't you use `encodeURIComponent()` as you say in the first sentence?

Comment: But what's the point? `decodeURIComponent()` simply reverses the encoding, so you get back the original string. The real solution was doubling the backslashes, e.g. `\\n`.